# Applications of Gauss-Bonnet theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, big-list

In wikipedia,I was pretty amazed to find a proof of [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)

using [Gauss Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Bonnet_theorem).

I think given how central it is to mathematics with its far reaching generalizations like Riemann-Roch Theorem and more,I am wondering if there are more.I would also be happy to see striking applications of its generalizations.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem - but I don't know if MO is the place to be asking this. 

Comment: thanks.but what i want is applications to prove some classical results


Comment: i don't think it is unsuitable to ask questions here specially when many questions have already been asked in a similiar vien


Comment: I don't think it makes sense to call Atiyah-Singer an application of Gauss-Bonnet (a generalization, sure).  But if applications of Atiyah-Singer to "classical results" would be answers to this question, then the question is *way* too broad.  If applications of only Gauss-Bonnet (and perhaps Gauss-Bonnet-Chern) are allowed, then there are probably a reasonable number of decent answers.  For instance, two surfaces with the same constant curvature and the same genus necessarily have the same area.

Comment: Not an application but an operator theoretical interpretation: http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0001

Answer (score 4):

Chern-Gauß-Bonnet implies that the volume of a hyperbolic manifold is a constant multiple of its Euler characteristics, with the constant factor depending on dimension only.

In particular, a hyperbolic manifold with $$\mid\chi(M)\mid=1$$ necessarily is the hyperbolic manifold of minimal volume in its dimension. Ratcliffe, Tschantz and Everitt have used this to find the hyperbolic manifolds of minimal volume in dimensions 4 and 6.

Answer (score 3):

Shameless plug: in [this note](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.6279v2) I showed that a *two*-dimensional analogue of the positive energy theorem follows essentially trivially from Gauss-Bonnet.

(Remark: positive energy theorems are two-dimensions is not new. But previously published results assume that spatial sections are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. The main contribution above is that this topological assumption can be removed as it is a consequence of the other assumptions + Gauss-Bonnet.)